# How can I get a list of output using requests library?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to download files from this library http://www.dli.ernet.in/ automatically, and would like to get a list of all the books corresponding to a particular language (Say: English)

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.dli.ernet.in/')
params = {'Language': 'English'}
```

But I am not sure how to proceed next. I need to mimic

1) Select Language

2) Click Search

3) Get a list of all the book names.

Comment: You would have to POST the parameter to mimic the form and then use BeautifulSoup to parse the resulting page. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: Actually, clicking `Search` on that form results in a `GET` request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do is figure out exactly what request your browser is making.  You can use the "web developer tools" in Firefox to do this:

- Show the web developer toolbox (Tools->Web Developer->Toggle Tools)
- Click on the "Network" tab
- Perform the search

This reveals that selecting "English" as the language results in the query:

> GET http://www.dli.ernet.in/cgi-bin/advsearch_db.cgi?perPage=25&listStart=0&r1=V1&title1=&author1=&year1=&year2=&subject1=Any&language1=English&scentre=Any&search=Search

We can reproduce this using the `requests` library by doing something like:

```
result = requests.get('http://www.dli.ernet.in/cgi-bin/advsearch_db.cgi',
                      params={
                          'language1': 'English',
                          'scentre': 'Any',
                          'listStart': '0',
                          'perPage': '25'
                      })
```

This will get us the text of the web page in `result.text`. You would
need to use an HTML parser (like `lxml.html` or `BeautifulSoup`) to
parse this and extract the list of books.  Note also that this appears to be a paged response, meaning you won't get *all* of the results with a single request.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't have experience with web development, so I learnt a lot from this post.

Comment: Glad to help out.  If this answers your question, consider checking the checkbox to the left of the answer.  This is both a way of saying "thanks" and also an indication that the question has been answered.

Comment: @maximusdooku That's called web scraping, not web development they're different topics.